# Is there a way to pass github repository credentials storing helm charts at install?

Tags: github-pages, kubernetes-helm, github-actions

I've followed this guide: https://dev.to/jamiemagee/how-to-host-your-helm-chart-repository-on-github-3kd to setup a private github helm chart repository, everything is working fine, github action scripts are testing the docs, releases are being made, but at the time of install it fails with a 404.

```
➜  ~ helm install --devel -f thor.job-export.values.yaml job-export sample/thor --debug
install.go:172: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:174: [debug] setting version to >0.0.0-0
Error: failed to fetch https://github.com/myuser/helm-charts/releases/download/thor-0.1.4/thor-0.1.4.tgz : 404 Not Found
```

Understanding that helm cannot fetch the *.tgz files because it seems it's not using my GitHub credentials.

I've tried to add the private github repo with this command:

```
helm repo add sample 'https://mytoken@raw.githubusercontent.com/myuser/helm-charts/gh-pages/'
```

Which seems to be able to gather the chart info in the error described above.

Is there a way to pass the github credentials at install time of the chart? tried this:

```
 helm install  -f thor.job-export.values.yaml --password mytoken --username myuser job-export sample/thor --debug
```

But fails with the same error... So, is there any way to pass the github repo user and password to helm at chart install ?

Comment: try adding your credentials during repo add: `help repo add --username user --password password sample 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myuser/helm-charts/gh-pages/'`

Comment: Tried that, same error

Comment: Include `--pass-credentials`